# Ist es richtig sowas zu sagen: "Nichts ist wichtiger im Leben als ein sehr toller Freund wie du (zu) haben"?

Tags: grammaticality

Ich möchte gern wissen, ob dieser Satz grammatisch richtig ist:

> Nichts ist wichtiger im Leben als ein sehr toller Freund wie du (zu) haben.

Gibt es Fehler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Korrekt ist:

> Nichts ist wichtiger im Leben, als einen so tollen Freund wie Dich zu haben.

- "Freund" ist hier das Akkusativobjekt von "haben", und muss folglich
  im Akkusativ stehen. "wie Dich" schließt sich d em Kasus an:

> ein Freund wie Du
>
> einem Freund wie Dir
>
> einen Freund wie Dich

- Vor dem "als" kann ein Komma stehen, weil es einen Infinitivsatz
  einleitet. Ich finde, ein Komma erleichtert den Lesefluss.
- Dass ich "Dich" großgeschrieben habe, ist ein Relikt aus der alten
  Rechtschreibung. Pronomina der zweiten Person großzuschreiben war
  darin ein Ausdruck von Höflichkeit, den ich beibehalten möchte.
- Das "zu" ist obligatorisch in Infinitivsätzen.

Comment: Wenn Du es ohne die rethorische Frage willst, fang den Satz an mit "Nichts ist wichtiger im Leben, als..." oder "Es gibt nichts wichtigeres im Leben[,] als..." - den Rest dann wie von Elena vorgeschlagen. Das groß geschriebene "Du" galt übrigens auch in der alten Rechtschreibung nur für direkte schriftliche Ansprache, z. B. in Briefen (nicht z. B. für zitierte wörtliche Rede). Ich finde es auch schön (und seit der letzten Revision der Reform 2006 ist es auch wieder erlaubt).

Comment: Danke sehr @fzwo, +1!

Comment: Ich finde die Umwandlung in eine rhetorische Frage nicht gerechtfertigt. Das kann zwar oft passend sein, ist aber nicht korrekturwürdig. Auch für 'so' statt 'sehr' sehe ich keinen Grund.

Comment: Die rhetorische Frage stand in der Originalversion der Frage (siehe Edits), die war nicht meine Idee. "So" statt "sehr" ergibt die Fügung "so <adjektiv> wie", die für mich typischer deutsch klingt als "sehr <adj> wie" oder gar "sehr toll".

Answer (score 3):

Als geringstmögliche Korrektur würde ich

> Nichts ist wichtiger im Leben, als einen sehr tollen Freund wie Dich zu haben.

statt

> Nichts ist wichtiger im Leben als ein sehr toller Freund wie du (zu) haben.

empfehlen.